# Resizing the canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I'm trying to design a web using flex-boxes in order to fit it to any kind of screen size. My main screen has a canvas, so... which is the best way to resize the canvas during the inizialitation?

I have tried these two ways. My first way was to use CSS and set a percentage for its size. For example, width=100% and height=100%. Despite the design worked, I found that there were a lot of issues when playing with the coords of my canvas. For example, when dragging an item, my mouse coords where amplified by ten times or so.
Despite I could manage that, I think it's not the best approach.

The second way was to set a fixed size when the onload and onresize events when they are fired. I was doing something like this:

```
window.initHeight = window.screen.height;
window.initWidth = window.screen.width;
/*The height of the navbar.*/
navbar.height = document.getElementById('navbar').offsetHeight;

canvas = document.getElementById('canvasStage');
canvas.width = window.initWidth;
canvas.height = window.initHeight - navbar.height;

canvas.setAttribute("width", canvas.width);
canvas.setAttribute("height", canvas.height);
```

The problem is that the height seems to be too big:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/31qJm.png
How could I fit the screen exactly through this way?

The third way, but I'll try to avoid it, is to set a fixed size and let the small screens to scroll on the page.

Thanks!

UPDATED:
This is my JSFiddle:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6IJd.png

Comment: Do you mean your canvas height and width is larger than window or vice versa...??

Comment: Don't forget there's a bunch of margins in a usual HTML document. Did you get rid of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height` returns the width and height of the screen which includes all bars (evrything you see on your screen).So you have to use `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` in order to get the view port height and width

Replace

```
window.initHeight = window.screen.height;
window.initWidth = window.screen.width;
```

with

```
window.initHeight = window.innerHeight;
window.initWidth = window.innerWidth;
```

Comment: Thanks Prasath K, but It seems that it is not enough:
http://i.imgur.com/NRTykLv.png
The sidebars show that it does not fit it yet.

This is my JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/na75d/1/

As Zeta pointed, I have got rid of any unuseful space. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's because of the scroll bars width and height .. I have tried everything but couldn't able to fix it .. Try setting the style for body like overflow:hidden; see whether it's ok fr you

Comment: Hi Prasath K, it worked for the width, but not for the height. I'll google for that, but meanwhile I'll substract 7px to the height. Thanks for all.